# How to scrape text of a span sibling span?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hello I'm trying to learn how to web scrape so I started by trying to web scrape my school menu.

Ive come into a problem were I can't get the menu items under a span class but instead get the the word within the same line of the span class "show".

[here is a short amount of the html text I am trying to work with](https://housing.ucdavis.edu/dining/menus/dining-commons/tercero/)

[image]

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver.exe')#changed this 
driver.get('https://housing.ucdavis.edu/dining/menus/dining-commons/tercero/')
results = []
content = driver.page_source
soups = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')
element=soups.findAll('span',class_ = 'collapsible-heading-status')
for span in element:
    print(span.text)
```

I have tried to make it into span.span.text but that wouldn't return me anything so can some one give me some pointer on how to extract the info under the collapsible-heading-status class.

Comment: Can't really tell, but I'd advise you to check your website through something like `postman` to see only the HTML returned by the first get request. Your browser probably loaded the information you're looking for after executing some JS calls to a backend, asynchronously. Chances are you don't even need to scrape a website to obtain that information. On the other hand, maybe just adding a `sleep(2)` (or more) will give selenium enough time to load and render everything and then you'll be able to parse the HTML as you see in the browser

Comment: FYI: `collapsible-heading-status` class does not exist in the server's response and doesn't load until some js code is executed at some point. I'd advise you to use only requests and BeautifulSoup and learn from that. It will teach you more and will be faster to execute.

Comment: I don't see a waffle though I am hungry now. Some good eating there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yummy waffles - As mentioned they are gone, but to get your goal an approach would be to select the names via `css selectors` using the `adjacent sibling combinator`:

```
for e in soup.select('.collapsible-heading-status + span'):
    print(e.text)
```

or with `find_next_sibling()`:

```
for e in soup.find_all('span',class_ = 'collapsible-heading-status'):
    print(e.find_next_sibling('span').text)
```

###### Example

To get the whole information for each in a structured way you could use:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("https://housing.ucdavis.edu/dining/menus/dining-commons/tercero/")

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')

data = []
    
for e in soup.select('.nutrition'):
    d = {
        'meal':e.find_previous('h4').text,
        'title':e.find_previous('h5').text,
        'name':e.find_previous('span').text,
        'description': e.p.text
        }
    d.update({n.text:n.find_next().text.strip(': ') for n in e.select('h6')})
    data.append(d)
data
```

###### Output

```
[{'meal': 'Breakfast',
  'title': 'Fresh Inspirations',
  'name': 'Vanilla Chia Seed Pudding with Blueberrries',
  'description': 'Vanilla chia seed pudding with blueberries, shredded coconut, and toasted almonds',
  'Serving Size': '1 serving',
  'Calories': '392.93',
  'Fat (g)': '36.34',
  'Carbohydrates (g)': '17.91',
  'Protein (g)': '4.59',
  'Allergens': 'Tree Nuts/Coconut',
  'Ingredients': 'Coconut milk, chia seeds, beet sugar, imitation vanilla (water, vanillin, caramel color, propylene glycol, ethyl vanillin, potassium sorbate), blueberries, shredded sweetened coconut (desiccated coconut processed with sugar, water, propylene glycol, salt, sodium metabisulfite), blanched slivered almonds'},
 {'meal': 'Breakfast',
  'title': 'Fresh Inspirations',
  'name': 'Housemade Granola',
  'description': 'Crunchy and sweet granola made with mixed nuts and old fashioned rolled oats',
  'Serving Size': '1/2 cup',
  'Calories': '360.18',
  'Fat (g)': '17.33',
  'Carbohydrates (g)': '47.13',
  'Protein (g)': '8.03',
  'Allergens': 'Gluten/Wheat/Dairy/Peanuts/Tree Nuts',
  'Ingredients': 'Old fashioned rolled oats (per manufacturer, may contain wheat/gluten), sunflower seeds, seedless raisins, unsalted butter, pure clover honey, peanut-free mixed nuts (cashews, almonds, sunflower oil and/or cottonseed oil, pecans, hazelnuts, dried Brazil nuts, salt), light brown beet sugar, molasses'},...]
```